# Forcing a view to unload when another tabButton is hit. (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My iPhone app has a tabBar at the bottom.

The 5th tab is rarely used... but pretty memory-intensive... so I want to make it UNLOAD each time it is exited (by the user clicking on a different tab).

But how?

I thought I just needed to call "[self viewDidUnload]" but that doesn't seem to do it.

Where is the "forceThisViewToUnload" and where should I put it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can call `didReceiveMemoryWarning` but its bit hacky way :)

Answer (score 0):

just make sure it's not referenced anywhere.
so remomve it from the view-stack, and if you own it, send it a release message.